# How to use tags in a hierarchy with Microsoft Outlook tasks?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016, tags, tasks

Is there any way to create a "tag hierarchy" in MS Outlook?

For example:

```
Chef
  Joe
  Bob
  Al

Ingredient
  Wet
    Oil
  Dry
    Flour
    Sugar
```

And then associate various chefs & ingredients to a "recipe task".

And, for example, if I were to click on the "Dry" tag, I would see all the tasks that were associated with the "Dry" tag or (maybe optionally) any of its subtags.

Comment: If you're unaware, this is available using GMail or Proton Mail's web GUIs instead.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid it is not feasible to be realized using the built-in features in Outlook.

An alternative I can think of it to take advantage of categories. You can create custom categories based on the tags and then assign the categories to the tasks. For example, tasks related to "Oil" can be assigned three categories (Ingredient, Wet, Oil). So that you can search using the categories to find the tasks you want.

Comment: Okay, but as far as I know, "category" the Outlook term for "tag". And categories are only single-level (you can't have a hierarchy of categories).